# Blender render GLSL shadow problem

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, light, shadows

i am fairly new to blender. I try to make something like this and using something call GLSL.
[image]

However, In my version, There is some problem in the shadow. The shadow is just a rectangle... What kind of problem is that

[image]

Here's the blender file =]

[image]

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file so I can take a look at it? It will be much easier to answer if we can look at the file itself.

Comment: The file has be uploaded =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your window material is set to cast a shadow, change it.

[image]

Also change the frustum size of the sun.

[image]